# Парсинг php кода и изменение его

Tags: php, парсер

Доброго всем времени суток, возникла некая проблема...

В бд хранится строка такого вида:

```
<div class="lol">{foreach(message)}<div class="123">{message.user}</div><div>{message.text}</div>{endforeach}</div>
```

Когда мы делаем запрос на показ этого контента, перед тем, как выдать ответ, мы парсим его.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы из такого: `{foreach(message)}` получилось такое: `<?=foreach($parent as $message);?>`

Проще говоря, чтобы получился такой исходный код

```
<div class="lol"><? foreach($parent as $message) ?><div class="123"><?=$message['user'];?></div><div><?=$message['text'];?></div><?=endforeach;?></div>
```

Comment: Это не "парсинг PHP", а парсинг чего-то другого. Поймём что есть "другое" (какой-то шаблонизатор?) - поймём как лучше. А пока - конкретная задача решается в лоб простейшим регекспом.

Comment: ну да ладно reqexp такое не решить, так как надо не просто заменить конкретное а проверить валидные ли инструкции, и наче не работающее приложение @PinkTux. А вообще это похоже на `blade` шаблон.

Comment: Вы очень невнимательно прочитали мой комментарий. В нём речь шла о конкретной задаче (в формулировке которой ни слова о валидации или вариабельности кода не было - была конкретная строка). Если же нужны все плюшки, начиная с разбора разных строк и заканчивая валидацией - пишите нормальный парсер. А ещё проще - модифицируйте уже готовый, из движка шаблонизатора, раз он известен.

Comment: Это самописный код. Сам контент храниться в базе, соответственно когда мы делаем запрос на выдачу определённого контента, мы должны сначала код подобного рода {message.user} преобразовать в php, то есть, к примеру есть функция, parseHtml() {}, она принимает 2 параметра, $params (Может быть как массив или с 1 входным данным) и сам $content, то есть parseHtml(array $params = array(), $content)
Далее, в контенте мы ищим все строки, которые содержат {$1} данные
То есть у нас в контенте есть {message.user}

Comment: Мы эту строку заменяем следующим образом = <?=$params['message']['user'];?> И когда уже выполнили полную замену Возвращаем уже правильный контент - который в последствии выведем

Comment: @DimaRRR ну так а в чем проблема? Алгоритм написали же)) теперь применяйте свой алгоритм. Заменяйте по заготовке один шаблон на другой, с учетом входных данных и инклудьте